# How to load a php file when pressed CTRL+V on body of website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I created a code which id like to have a function that users must press CTRL+V then when it press, it will load the value. Heres my code. please help me.

My code is not working at first but it needs to pressed CTRL+V two times to display entered value in input.

Please help me. Thanks!

```
<?php
if($_GET["f"]==1){
echo $_GET["id_number"];
}
else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var isCtrl = false;
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
 if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}).keydown(function (e) {
if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
if(e.which == 86 && isCtrl == true) {
    document.getElementById('id_number').focus();
    document.getElementById('Button').click();
 }
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Button").click(function(){   
var id_number = document.getElementById('id_number');
$("#Content").html('<img src="http://tinyurl.com/7al6hv5">').load('1.php?f=1&id_number='+id_number.value+'');
});
});
</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="this.select();" value="" id="id_number">
<input type="submit" value="Load" id="Button">
<div id="Content"></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this works perfectly fine for me on Chrome. On what browser are you trying it?

Comment: If you never get this to work on any other browser, you'll quickly find that it's a reserved Windows / PC function for pasting. Used in conjunction with CTRL-C. Good luck though, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be at first the element wasnt ready, so you can try for

```
$(document).live('keyup',function (e) {
 if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}).live('keydown',function (e) {
if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
if(e.which == 86 && isCtrl == true) {
    document.getElementById('id_number').focus();
    document.getElementById('Button').click();
 }
});
});

//edit

$("#Button").live('click',function(){   ...
```

Comment: Still it needs to repeat pressing CTRL+V :(

Comment: So it means, the button needs to click inable to load or show the value? WHAT i mean is if CTRL+V pressed it will load the value. And what you've given is it need to click the button. btw. thanks

Comment: no. replacing your code with live() is for Attaching an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated (http://api.jquery.com/live/). You should use `.on()` instead.